# encode and decode int variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I decode and encode int variables in Objective-C?

This is what I have done so far, but application is terminating at that point.

Whats the mistake here?

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
   [coder encodeInt:count forKey:@"Count"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder
{
   [[decoder decodeIntForKey:@"Count"]copy];
   return self;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are not assigning the decoded int to any variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[decoder decodeIntForKey:@"Count"]` returns an `int`. And your sending the message `copy` to that `int` -> crash.

In Objective-C simple data types aren't objects. So you can't send messages to them. Ints are simple c data types.

Answer (score 6):

V1ru8 is right.  However, I prefer to encode ints as NSNumbers. Like this:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.count] forKey:@"Count"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.count = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Count"] intValue];
    }
    return self;
}
```